# Webpack and Typescript `__extends`

Tags: typescript, webpack

I write project with help of TypeScript. Project divided into many modules.
I bundle all modules into one file with Webpack.

For each module-class, which extends from parent class, webpack added TypeScript `__extends` helper.
As result - i got many repeated code.

```
/***/ },
/* 24 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var DeepExtend_1 = __webpack_require__(6);

//...

exports.SafariDetector = SafariDetector;


/***/ },
/* 25 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var DeepExtend_1 = __webpack_require__(6);

//...

exports.SafariMobileDetector = SafariMobileDetector;
```

So, any way to fix that?

Comment: This is the default behavior of the TypeScript compiler whenever it detects the "extends" keyword. Since the compiler doesn't know if you're going to bundle the output into one file or more, it emits the snippet wherever the keyword is.

Comment: After googling i found `--noEmitHelpers` flag, which disable helpers. But now i need manually include all TS helpers with Webpack https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-helpers. 
I at home now, but tomorrow i try do that with `imports-loader` https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#importing or with something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Please look at @goenning's answer and webpack.ProvidePlugin example for that:

   ```
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       __extends: path.join(__dirname, './src', 'extends.ts')
   })
   ```
2. We could use `"importHelpers": true` option in the **tsconfig**: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html
   But it adds **all** ts helpers without duplication (I've tried it with **ts-loader**).

I've chosen second variant because it is not a great overhead.

Answer (score 7):

Webpack's `ProvidePlugin` actually has an undocumented feature: you can configure it with an array instead of a string and it'll extract the given object path from the exports of a module.

This allows you to make use of TypeScript's official `tslib` module, which exports all the desired functions.

The following code works with `webpack@2.2.1`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '__assign': ['tslib', '__assign'],
    '__extends': ['tslib', '__extends'],
})
```

Make sure to force Webpack to use the ES6 module version of `tslib`:

```
aliases: {
    'tslib$': 'tslib/tslib.es6.js',
}
```

And configure your `tsc`/`tsconfig.json` not to emit the helper functions for every module:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
    }
}
```

**Edit**: My pull-request for a documentation update has been merged, so you'll find this on the official website as well, now: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution would be cofiguring TypeScript to omit those helpers when compiling and write it by yourself, once and in a single file that will be later bundled by webpack.

Set `compilerOptions.noEmitHelpers` to `true` on your `tsconfig.json` file.

Create a `extends.js` with `__extends` function definition ([typescript-helpers](https://npmjs.com/package/typescript-helpers)) and add it into your  webpack bundle.

Never tried that, but I've done something similar [here](http://goenning.net/2016/01/25/how-to-achieve-100-code-coverage-when-using-typescript/) regarding `__awaiter` and code coverage.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i google same solution. But how i can correct import and include once all helpers inside Webpack modules?

Comment: Looks like `ProvidePlugin` is what i'm looking for.